# Как сделать k8s кластер доступным?

Tags: dns, kubernetes, tls, certificate

Настраиваю k8s кластер на Яндекс облаке и столкнулся с проблемой получения TLS сертификата ingress контроллером при помощи cert-manager.

*Имя домена специально заменено на другое!*

Описание ситуации:
Куплен домен `mydomain.ru` на `nic.ru`, там же указаны перенаправления DNS на `ns1.timeweb.ru` и т.д. `ns1.yandexcloud.net` и т.д. На таймвебе находится один из старых сервисов с поддоменом `subdomain1.mydomain.ru`, а на яндекс облаке находится новый сервис с другим поддоменом `subdomain2.mydomain.ru`, но проверив через `dig` с этой командой

```
dig @8.8.8.8 subdomain2.mydomain.ru
```

То он выдает таймвебовский `ns1.timeweb.ru` и `mydomain.ru`, а не `ns1.yandexcloud.net`, хотя A запись в Cloud DNS яндекс облака есть. И как я писал выше - доступ с моей локальной сети я имею, а пробуя зайти с телефона через мобильную сеть мне пишет, что такого сервера нет. И как я понимаю cert-manager не может достучаться до сервиса и выдать сертификат.
Как в данном случае настроить dns, чтобы была возможность использовать два сервера с разными dns серверами?

Дополнение 1:
После проверки через dig subdomain1.mydomain.ru другого сервиса на timeweb я обнаружил, что вместо ns сервера выдается статический ip. И сделав ip балансировщика кластера статическим в консоли я получил доступ к сервису. Буду копать дальше.

Дополнение 2:
Я попробовал в балансировщике сделать ip адрес статическим, но записи на dns google и cloudflare остались от timeweb, а не от яндекс облака.

Дополнение 3:
Ошибка в challege k8s
`10.30.128:53` - это ip и порт kube-dns внутри кластера

```
Reason:      Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: failed to perform self check GET request 'http://subdomain2.mydomain.ru/.well-known/acme-challenge/Jl0E9aw_gq6nLoFBme5-IaSbW0ygRbqjwA1Hcsdw-JA': Get "http://subdomain2.mydomain.ru/.well-known/acme-challenge/Jl0E9aw_gq6nLoFBme5-IaSbW0ygRbqjwA1Hcsdw-JA": dial tcp: lookup subdomain2.mydomain.ru on 10.30.128.2:53: no such host
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы заключалось в том, чтобы убрать DNS записи в Cloud DNS в Яндекс облаке и сделать их в timeweb, а так же убрать перенаправление на `ns1.yandexcloud.net` и т.д. на nic.ru.

Это временное решение, потому что с timeweb рано или поздно придется переезжать. Но все заработало.

Вот вам хокку

```
It's not DNS
There's no way it's DNS
It was DNS
```